# Working with non-english characters in columns of spark scala dataframes

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, encoding, utf-8

Here is part of a file I am trying to load into a dataframe:

> alphabet|Sentence|Comment1
>
> è|Small e|None
>
> Ü|Capital U|None
>
> ã|Small a|
>
> Ç|Capital C|None

When I load this file into a dataframe all the non-english characters get converted into boxes. Tried to give `option("encoding","UTF-8")`, but there is no change.

```
val nonEnglishDF = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("delimiter","|").option("header",true).option("encoding","UTF-8").load(hdfs file path)
```

Please let me know is there is any solution for this. I need to save the file finally with no change in the non-english characters. Currently when the file is saved, it puts boxes or question mark instead of the non-english characters.

Answer (score 1):

use `decode` function on that column:

```
decode(col("column_name"), "US-ASCII")

//It should work with one of these ('US-ASCII', 'ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8', 'UTF-16BE', 'UTF-16LE', 'UTF-16')
```

Comment: Hi Jay... Actually I got solution for it. It works with ISO-8859-1 encoding. Doesn't work with UTF-16(BE,LE or plain) (converts it into Chinese looking chars). Didn't try US-ASCII. Thanks for the reply

Comment: whenever I'm in situation like this, I iterate through them until I find one that works. glad to hear that you were able to figure it out.

Comment: What charset to use if there swedish characters in a csv file

Comment: i'd say UTF-8 should be able to read those.

Answer (score 1):

It works with option("encoding","ISO-8859-1"). e.g.

```
val nonEnglishDF = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("delimiter","|").option("header",true).option("encoding","ISO-8859-1").load(hdfs file path)
```