# Pyspark - Reading a csv file and retaining the original special characters

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

I am reading a csv file which has only data like below

```
Country        State      City
MÉXICO         Neu Leon   Monterrey    
MÉXICO         Chiapas    ATLÁNTICO
```

I tried reading the file with encoding = 'utf8' and 'ISO-8859-1' in pyspark dataframe but values are getting changed like below -

In option("encoding", "utf-8")

```
Country          State      City
Mï¿½XICO         Neu Leon   Monterrey    
Mï¿½XICO         Chiapas    ATLï¿½NTICO
```

In option("encoding", "ISO-8859-1")

```
Country        State      City
M?XICO         Neu Leon   Monterrey    
M?XICO         Chiapas    ATL?NTICO
```

here is the spark read statement

```
spark.read.format("csv").option("quote", "\"").option("escape", "\"").option('multiLine', True).option("encoding", "ISO-8859-1").option("header", "true").load("country.csv")
```

option("encoding", "mbcs") and option("encoding", "ansi") gives errror.

What can I do to retain the original text which is in input file?? Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the encoding you're declaring the one used to write the file?

Comment: I am doing the encoding in to read and write both. All I want is to retain the original special text which coming in input file and not to change it. How can I do that

Comment: Its already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64261341/working-with-non-english-characters-in-columns-of-spark-scala-dataframes/64265197?noredirect=1#comment113659991_64265197).

Comment: I tried with option("encoding", "ISO-8859-1") already. Its not giving the same result. Can it be possible its not working with multiline = true option

Answer (score 0):

Rread it in without encoding, then create a new column:

```
df.withColumn("some_col_name", decode(col("column_name"), "ISO-8859-1"))

# One of these will give you what you need. ('US-ASCII', 'ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8', 'UTF-16BE', 'UTF-16LE', 'UTF-16')
```